# What are the pros and cons of a m.example.com vhost vs subfolder rewrite to m.example.com?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm having an issue right now at work with another employee who wants to use a subfolder /m (mobile) and have it push the folder structure to the front of the url like m.example.com

I currently have it setup that m.example.com is being told what file path to use through vhosts.

His method: example.com/m/index points at m.example.com/index and redirects through htaccess

My method: m.example.com is a virtual host created in httpd.conf and is told to use the folder path example.com/m as its root

What are the pros and cons of doing either method? I personally feel the vhost is the "proper" way and cleaner way. I don't want to throw more garbage in my htaccess file if its not needed.

Comment: Yes no doubt setting right `DocumentRoot` from vhost is the correct way.

Comment: Im having a hard time explaining to him why we should do it through vhost....Could you give me some reasons to help persuade him?

Comment: Performance is one reason since server doesn't need to process .htaccess rules, another is security since no hackers/spammer can tweak .htaccess rule to cause disruption.

Comment: is there actually set m.example.com to use example.com/mobile/ in htaccess? I cant get it to work without using vhost

Comment: Using .htaccess `m.example.com  => example.com/mobile/` will actually be a redirect not just silent rewrite unless you use mod_proxy

Comment: Does something like this work? RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m.example.com     
                       RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/mobile/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: Yes it will work but URL will also change to `http://example.com/mobile/` in the browser.

Comment: So there is no way to put a folder or query in front of a site without using mod_proxy? (or sub directory set in DocumentRoot of vhost). EX: chicago.example.com = example.com?location=chicago OR m.example.com = example.com/mobile. Sorry im grinding on this, I have to explain to them why I cant do it the way they want.

Comment: That is right. If domain name is changing (`m.example.com => example.com`) then it won't be silent rewrite and it will be full redirect unless you use `mod_proxy`